# Can I remove the white circle at the bottom of the model?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

As for the title, I am a beginner of Android. When running github's sceneform-sample, I found that when the model appeared on the screen, a white circle would appear under the model. What methods can I use to remove the white circle at the bottom?

I have uploaded a picture so that you can understand my question more intuitively.

[image: White Circle]

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `node.select()`, it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this before, but as long as I placed enough andy, the white ring appeared again when andy switched with each other.

Comment: Oh, andy is the little green robot in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have found an answer to your question in GitHub but for completeness here are some examples in Kotlin, setting the SelectionVisualiser, which allows you determine what is shown or not shown under a selected TransformableNode.

**Example 1**

Changing the SelectionVisualiser for the entire activity:

```js
class StartViewMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //included in the class variables
    private lateinit var defaultSelectionVisualiser:SelectionVisualizer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //As part of OnCreate, set the selection visualiser
        arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer = CustomSelectionVisualiser()
        
    }

    private class CustomSelectionVisualiser(): SelectionVisualizer {
       //Class providing a custom TransformableNode SelectionVisualiser
       //This particular custom visualiser shows no image
       override fun applySelectionVisual(node:BaseTransformableNode){}
       override fun removeSelectionVisual(node:BaseTransformableNode){}
    }
 }
```

**Example 2**

Changing the SelectionVisualiser programatically during part of your program flow:

```js
class StartViewMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //included in the class variables
    private lateinit var defaultSelectionVisualiser:SelectionVisualizer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //As part of OnCreate, get the default selection visualiser
        defaultSelectionVisualiser = arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer
        
    }    


    fun toggelSelectionVisulaisers() {
        //Switch between the default and the custom selectionVisualisers
        if (arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer == defaultSelectionVisualiser) { 
            arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer = CustomSelectionVisualiser) else
        } else { 
            arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer = defaultSelectionVisualiser                arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer = CustomSelectionVisualiser) else
        }


    private class CustomSelectionVisualiser(): SelectionVisualizer {
       //Class providing a custom TransformableNode SelectionVisualiser
       //This particular custom visualiser shows no image
       override fun applySelectionVisual(node:BaseTransformableNode){}
       override fun removeSelectionVisual(node:BaseTransformableNode){}
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,

there is two way one is don't select the model,
like don't call bellow method

```
node.select()
```

Second one is aplly transperent selection visualiser

- First Create a Transparent Visualiser class like bellow

  ```
   class BlanckSelectionVisualizer : SelectionVisualizer {
        override fun applySelectionVisual(var1: BaseTransformableNode) {}
        override fun removeSelectionVisual(var1: BaseTransformableNode) {}
    }
  ```

Then after applying it on ArFragmnet like bellow

```
arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer = BlanckSelectionVisualizer()
```

I suggest use second one